# Load json once times and use the content file OUTSIDE the function

Tags: javascript, json

sorry, can someone show me the code and explain me, how to I can load only once the json file, and use all the content file OUTSIDE the function?

```
    let jsonCompleto
    
    fetch('uno.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        todo = data.length
        console.log(todo)
        jsonCompleto = data
        console.log(jsonCompleto) // this return all the json file correctly
    
    })

console.log(jsonCompleto) // this return undefined
// how can load only once the json file and use all content of json file OUTSIDE the function ?
```

Comment: Please don't re-ask the exact same question when your previous attempts have already been closed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use async/await

```js
"use strict";

const myFetch = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  return response.json()
}

const myFunc = async () => {
  data = await myFetch()
  
  console.log(data)
}

myFunc()
```

you can see the [fetch free documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: and now `jsonCompleto` holds a promise...

Comment: with await instruction should not return a promise

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I recibe:Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at otro.js:20
    at async myFunc (otro.js:20)

Comment: I update my response... and I provide a documentation

Comment: `async` functions always returns a promise. Once you enter async land that's where you live.

Comment: now yes. this can works... you can use data inside the myFunction

Comment: thanks, now, how can I access to one value of this file.  My json file: [
  {
    "eng": "hello",
    "ita": "ciao"
  },
  {
    "eng": "today",
    "ita": "hoy"
  },
  {
    "eng": "yesteday",
    "ita": "ieri"
  }
]

Comment: by key. example data[0], data[1]... etc.. of course if is an array

Comment: const myFetch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('uno.json')
    return response.json()
  }
  
  const myFunc = async () => {
    return await myFetch()
  }
  
  const jsonCompleto = myFunc()

  console.log(jsonCompleto[1])  // return indefined

Comment: you shold be use the data inside `myFunc`. myFunc function return a promise. add you logic inside `myFunc`

Comment: In strict mode, your code throws _"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at myFunc"_

Comment: thanks Franklin'j Gil'z / Pilchard and Phil !!